# Problem with import SQL queries to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE security_user
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
    roles JSON NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_52825A88E7927C74 (email),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
```

When I try use it in php error I have error:

> 1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_52825A88E7927C7' in line 1

I have installed Xampp Server: https://www.apachefriends.org/pl/download.html

How can I repair this?

Comment: which db version  you are using ??

Comment: 'As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: XAMPP is using MariaDB 10.1.X - JSON is available from MariaDB 10.2 - Check you exact version with `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: 10.1.38-MariaDB

Comment: Then you are lucky, because now you have more reasons to create a clean normalized design. Don't store `roles` in a JSON array. Create a many-to-many relation instead.

Answer (score 1):

The current version (actually 7.1.28, 7.2.17 and 7.3.4) of *XAMPP* is using *MariaDB 10.1.38*. This version doesn't support the `JSON` datatype. At least version *10.2.7* is required (see [JSON Data Type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/)).

In your case I would consider to define a clean normalized relation (user <--> role) instead of of storing the roles in a JSON array.

Comment: Paul, I edited your answer and added the **current** version (as the date of today, april the 29th 2019) of XAMPP  (This answer may change on futurs versions)

Comment: @Cid Tanks - That's more accurate then just "current".